# Receive data from static class

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, http

I have utils class which is fetching data from external API in static method:

```
@Component
public class Util {


    private Util() {

    }


    public static List<Movie> getMovies(){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        String resourceURL = "< a loooong url>" 
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<Results> response = restTemplate.exchange(resourceURL,  HttpMethod.GET, entity, Results.class);
        Results results = response.getBody();
        List<Movie> movies = results.getResults();
        return movies;
    }
}
```

I know that data is properly fetched from server, but I don't have any idea why I can't transfer it to my rest controller:

```
@RestController
public class MovieController {



    @RequestMapping(value ="/movies", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Movie> getMovies(){
        return Util.getMovies();
    }

}
```

It returns me 404 no message available..

Any ideas guys? ;)

Greetings

Comment: HTTP status code 404 is "Not found". This means your request doesn't match any of your registered endpoints. Make sure your GET request is pointed at localhost:port/movies.

Comment: On a general point your class not the methods on it should not be static. Just annotate it with `@Component` and Spring will create an instance of it that you can inject into your controller.

I'd also recommend renaming Util to something meaningful, like MovieService.

What's throwing the 404, the call to the MovieController or to the Util restTemplate call  ?

Comment: Could be that he does not have `@ResponseBody` annotation in his controller method.

Comment: How do you try to access your endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you have to make the method static? Switch it to a non static method then you can autowire it in your controller.

```
@Component
public class Util {

    public List<Movie> getMovies(){
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        String resourceURL = "< a loooong url>" 
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<Results> response = restTemplate.exchange(resourceURL,  HttpMethod.GET, entity, Results.class);
        Results results = response.getBody();
        List<Movie> movies = results.getResults();
        return movies;
    }
}
```

Since its a component you can now autowire it and you also have to add the `@ResponseBody` annotation to your controller.

```
@RestController
public class MovieController {

    @Autowired
    private Util util;

    @RequestMapping(value ="/movies", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Movie> getMovies(){
        return util.getMovies();
    }
}
```